# DB2 XMLSERIALIZE in RPG ILE

Tags: xml, db2, db2-400, rpg

So I'm trying to develop a function in AS400 RPG that receives 4 String parameters, uses DB2 XMLSERIALIZE to build an XML Header using said parameters and returns that header in a string. The return string shows different characters in the tag values when I use an RPG variable. I think maybe the problem is the character coding, but I've tried many solutions and none works.

Here's the code of the RPG function:

```
dcl-proc SWFS02801_generaHeaderMX export;
  dcl-pi *n Ind;
    bicFrom        Char(12);
    bicTo          Char(12);
    BizMsgIdr      Char(20);
    MsgDefIdr      Char(20);
    AppHeaderData  Char(2000);
  end-pi;
  dcl-s AppHeader   SQLTYPE(CLOB:2000);
  dcl-s bicFromClob SQLTYPE(CLOB:12);
  dcl-c BizSvc 'swift.cbprplus.01';

  bicFromClob_DATA = bicFrom;
  Exec Sql SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(
   XMLELEMENT(NAME "AppHdr", XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT
     'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02'),
   XMLFOREST(
     XMLELEMENT(NAME "FiId", XMLELEMENT(NAME "FinInstId",
       XMLFOREST( :bicFrom as  "BicFi")  ) ) as "Fr",
     XMLELEMENT(NAME "FiId", XMLELEMENT(NAME "FinInstId",
       XMLFOREST( :bicTo as  "BicFi")  )) as "To",
     :BizMsgIdr as "BizMsgIdr",
     :MsgDefIdr as "MsgDefIdr",
     :BizSvc as "BizSvc",
     CubDDat.UbdFGenFec(Current date) as "CredDt"

   )
) as CLOB(2000) ) AS RESULTADO
INTO :AppHeader
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
  If SQLCODE = 0;
    AppHeaderData =  AppHeader_DATA;
    return *on;
  Else;
    return *off;
  ENDIF;
END-PROC;
```

The problem is specifically in the variables: bicFrom, bicTo, BizMsgIdr, MsgDefIdr.

The expected XML Header is the following:

```
<AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">
  <Fr>
    <FiId>
      <FinInstId>
        <BicFi>BICFROM1</BicFi>
      </FinInstId>
    </FiId>
  </Fr>
  <To>
    <FiId>
      <FinInstId>
        <BicFi>BICTO1</BicFi>
      </FinInstId>
    </FiId>
  </To>
  <BizMsgIdr>tstBizMsgIdr</BizMsgIdr>
  <MsgDefIdr>tstMsgDefIdr</MsgDefIdr>
  <BizSvc>swift.cbprplus.01</BizSvc>
  <CredDt>2021-12-28T06:00:00.0Z</CredDt>
</AppHdr>
```

And the (incorrect) output that is returned is the following (notice the tags **BicFi**, **BizMsgIdr**, **MsgDefIdr**, **BizSvc**)   :

```
<AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">
  <Fr>
    <FiId>
      <FinInstId>
        <BicFi>wsnDxtnW1PFAQEBA</BicFi>
      </FinInstId>
    </FiId>
  </Fr>
  <To>
    <FiId>
      <FinInstId>
        <BicFi>wsnDxuPW8UBAQEBA</BicFi>
      </FinInstId>
    </FiId>
  </To>
  <BizMsgIdr>oqPCianUoofJhJlAQEBAQEBAQEA=</BizMsgIdr>
  <MsgDefIdr>oqPUoofEhYbJhJlAQEBAQEBAQEA=</MsgDefIdr>
  <BizSvc>oqaJhqNLg4KXmZeTpKJL8PE=</BizSvc>
  <CredDt>2021-12-28T06:00:00.0Z</CredDt>
</AppHdr>
```

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance!!!

Edit:
Here's the caller code:

```
Ctl-opt  bnddir('SERVICEBCO') DftActGrp( *No ) actgrp('QILE');

//TXT containing the procedure prototype
/include LIBLCF/QSRCTXT,SWFS02801H


Dcl-S bicFrom           Char(12) Inz( 'BICFROM1' );
Dcl-S bicTo             Char(12) Inz( 'BICFTO1' );
Dcl-S BizMsgIdr         Char(20) Inz( 'stBizMsgIdr' );
Dcl-S MsgDefIdr         Char(20) Inz( 'stMsgDefIdr');
Dcl-S CreDt             Char(30) Inz(*blanks);
Dcl-S headerMX          Char(2000) Inz( *Blanks );


EXEC SQL SET OPTION CLOSQLCSR = *ENDMOD;
If Swfs02801_generaHeaderMX(bicFrom :bicTo : BizMsgIdr : MsgDefIdr : headerMX );
   dsply %subst(headerMX:1:30);
   //dsply just to check the result 
Endif;


*inlr = *on;
```

Prototype:

```
       /if defined(SWFS02801_INCLUDED)
        /eof
        /endif
        /define SWFS02801_INCLUDED

        dcl-pr SWFS02801_generaHeaderMX ind;
          bicFrom        Char(12);
          bicTo          Char(12);
          BizMsgIdr      Char(20);
          MsgDefIdr      Char(20);
          AppHeader      Char(2000);
        end-pr;
```

The system and job CSSID is 65535.

The problem happens when serializing by using the passed variables (bicfrom, bicto, BizMsgIdr and AppHeaderData ).

Comment: How is the procedure being called?  That doesn't look like a CCSID issue to me, the output values look encoded (base64 perhaps?)

Comment: The procedure is encapsulated in a service program. The caller is a simple program that passes parameters: `
Dcl-S bicFrom           Char(12) Inz( 'BICFROM1' );
Dcl-S bicTo             Char(12) Inz( 'BICFTO1' );
Dcl-S BizMsgIdr         Char(20) Inz( 'stBizMsgIdr' );
Dcl-S MsgDefIdr         Char(20) Inz( 'stMsgDefIdr');
Dcl-S headerMX          Char(2000) Inz( *Blanks );


EXEC SQL SET OPTION CLOSQLCSR = *ENDMOD;
If Swfs02801_generaHeaderMX(bicFrom :bicTo : BizMsgIdr : MsgDefIdr : headerMX );
   dsply %subst(headerMX:1:30);
Endif;


*inlr = *on;`

Comment: can you add the calling code to your question?  Also include the prototype ( you are /COPY a single prototype into both caller and callee correct? )  Indicate where/how you are seeing the incorrect results.  Lastly, what's the system and job CCSID's?

Comment: I have posted the edit. Thanks for the help!